# TypeError passing a function to a React click handler

Tags: reactjs

My (simplified) React component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

export default function MyList(setPanel) {

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(setPanel);
    setPanel('support');
  };

  return (
    <List>
      <ListItem button key="Support" onClick={handleClick}>
        <ListItemText primary="Support" />
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  );
}
```

and the console log is showing `setPanel` to be a function but then I'm getting a

> TypeError: setPanel is not a function

when I click on the ListItem in the app. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't destructure the props:

```
export default function MyList({setPanel})
```

Since `props` is an object containing `setPanel`, you are getting `setPanel` isn't a function.